# jasmine node+webdriverjs : test client function calls

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, jasmine-node

let's say I got this simple script running in the browser:

```
function foo(a,b){

 return a > b;

}
```

how can I test this function  using webdriverjs and jasmine for node?

Is it even possible to do it? Till now I've been coming across DOM assertion examples .

P.S. I've just started out with testing